# Ubuntu server integration in Mac Finder

Tags: networking, server, mac

I use netatalk to communicate via afp between an Ubuntu server 20.04 and Macbooks.
In Finder on the Macs a WD nas, a Mac Mini server and other MacBooks (all using AFP) appear from the start as icons you can click on and access.
To have the ubuntu server appear Mac users have to every time press Cmd+K in Finder and then enter afp://192.168.1.2 in a popup dialog window.
Is there a way to configure afp on the ubuntu server in such a way that a clickable icon appears in the Mac Finder from the start?

Comment: This question is how to edit a MAC. Probably best to ask on MAC Forums.

Comment: No, it’s not about a Mac. It’s about Ubuntu server configuration / afp-network configuration. The Mac is merely the passive, receiving side.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are missing is an avahi service file for AFP so that the Mac client and "discover" it.

***Note: I haven't done this in a very long time since MacOS has moved on to using SMB / Samba but this is easily undone simply by removing the afp.service file.***

First, install avahi on your server:

```
sudo apt install avahi-daemon
```

Then create the service file at: `/etc/avahi/services/afp.service`

With this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?>
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">
<service-group>
<name replace-wildcards="yes">AFP %h</name>
<service>
<type>_afpovertcp._tcp</type>
<port>548</port>
</service>
<service>
<type>_device-info._tcp</type>
<port>0</port>
<txt-record>model=Xserve</txt-record>
</service>
</service-group>
```

If everything works Finder should see it as "AFP *your-server-host-name*"